# Can I create dhcp reservation with powershell server 2008 r2

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, dhcp

Can I create a dhcp reservation with powershell in windows server 2008 r2?

I can see that they have beautiful **cmdlets** that are apparently only used on 2012.

Does this mean I would have to do it using `netsh`, via

```
netsh dhcp server \\servername scope <subnetID> add reservedip <IPaddress> <MacAddress> "ReservationName" "Comment"
```

If possible it would be nice to use those new shiny cmdlets

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those cmdlets can also be used to manage DHCP server running on Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2, but executed on a machine that supports 'DHCP Server PowerShell cmdlets', for example windows 8, but you cannot run on a Windows server 2008 r2.

> Since DHCP Server WMI provider is not supported on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2, you need to use –ComputerName while using DHCP PowerShell to manage a DHCP server running on Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2.

Read this post for a good detailed explanation: [Microsoft Technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/teamdhcp/archive/2013/05/24/using-windows-8-dhcp-powershell-cmdlets-with-dhcp-server-running-on-windows-server-2008-or-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx)

**Example**

```
Add-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName dhcpwin2k8server.contoso.com -Name "Lab-1 Network" -StartRange 10.10.10.1 -EndRange 10.10.10.254 -SubnetMask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Thanks. So try just running the commands from 2012 remotely to 2008 server?

Comment: exactly, read the post I linked, because you must specify the –ComputerName parameter "since DHCP Server WMI provider is not supported on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2"

Comment: sweet, thanks for that, i'll spin up a 2012 vm and get testing.